# I am doing something I didn't sign up for in the first place

Tags: new-job, job-satisfaction

Since my first days in this company, I kept feeling something was wrong.

I strove to dismiss all my worries ... but it was pointless, especially when I was not invited (I was forgotten) to the first official meeting to introduce the new project.

I was assigned a component of a software that works with technology I know nothing of ... and I eventually accepted (I decided to be optimistic).

Once the project started, I was assigned new components with other technologies ...

I made enough sacrifices so far, and then they came to me for more sacrifices, whereas my colleagues are resistant and reckless, that's when I started to question this job.

A sudden flashback was triggered, and I realized that I was doing nothing of what I expected from this job. As a matter of fact, there is absolutely no correlation between what I am doing and the job offer.

There are many basic discrepancies that I don't even need to mention in here.

Isn't this an alarming situation? Or is it a regular one?

Comment: I think you're going to have to get more specific with your "discrepancies" here because I don't see anything that isn't normal for life as a software developer. If you expect to not find yourself learning new things on a regular basis and having to familiar with technologies you didn't previously know, you should probably look for a different line of work.

Comment: go back and check the job desc, most likely it has some language to the effect of "other tasks as needed" : p

Comment: @alroc I changed my job to work on new techniques like design patterns and APIs, not to go back to 90s code and correct bugs of some procedural-oriented program ...

Comment: Business needs change. You were hired as a software developer, never for a specific project only, and you are working on code. If they hired you as an accountant and made you a programmer or hired you as a programmer and made you a janitor, you might have a point.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a perfectly normal situation to me.  That's the nature of software - one project may be cutting edge research and development, the next may be maintaining an obsolete system.

Think of it as a learning opportunity.  If you only ever do things you are comfortable with, you will never be any good at anything but that one thing.  If you take the opportunity to learn new things (or even old things) then after a few years you will be the person that everyone wants on their project.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this sounds like a growth opportunity.  You're still getting paid, right?  No one's singled you out personally to make your life miserable, right?  (It happens).  You could stand a stroke of gratitude because there are many people out there who'd love to take your place **right** now.

Friend, all you can really expect is *change*.  You can embrace it and deal with it, or whimper and hide in a cave; and either way, life will move right on.  Choose wisely.

Comment: So, I was hired to repair 1940s cars? That's another way to be outdated in the mechanic job market, for instance.

Comment: NO, my friend.  That's a way to make yourself valuable in a niche that every other person can't get into.  You're just looking at it in the wrong way.

Comment: I value your optimism, but I am too old and was perpetually disappointed to be optimistic ...

Comment: @Bonaparte I'd like to compare notes.  Were you ever homeless, crippled by a stroke, and told you'd never work again?  Being optimistic is the only thing that can get you out of messes.

Comment: +1 change jobs or change attitude. Or, both! Nothing wrong with changing your attitude whilst looking for a new job